# How to disable/autoanswer dialog box about macros/VB Project when resaving xls to xlsx with win32com.client?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

When using this code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

input_files = os.listdir(parent_dir)
input_files = [parent_dir + i for i in input_files if i.endswith('.xls') and not i.endswith('.xlsx')]
for input_file in input_files:
    if not os.path.isfile(input_file.replace('.xls', '.xlsx')):
        excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(input_file)
        wb.SaveAs(input_file + "x", FileFormat=51)  # FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension
        wb.Close()  # FileFormat = 56 is for .xls extension
        excel.Application.Quit()
```

on excel files containing some macros/VB Project often messagebox shows up with warning, that all macros/VB Project will be lost, I would like to somehow automatically answer it, for example, "Yes", or maybe there is some parameter for SaveAs function or settings for

win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')?

Now I can just resave files as xlsm with FileFormat=51, but by some security reasons I don't want to do this, I really don't need this macros/VB Projects in my files.

Tried excel.DisplayAlerts = False - not helped.

Also thinking about something like pywinauto, but maybe it overkill and maybe there is more elegant solution?

Comment: Try stripping out the macros / forms and any VBA sitting behind the workbook / worksheet objects first.  Then you shouldn't get the dialog.  Make sure you have programmatic access to the VBE.

Comment: Short notice - saving as xlsm will not bring on this dialog, also FileFormat=52 is xlsm format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, interesting thing, if you save in xlsm, not in xlsx, Excel would not ask questions about containing macros/VB Project, and you can open xlsm in openpyxl like it xlsm, so, how to resave in xlsm:

```
def resave_xls_file_as_xlsx_or_xlsm(in_xls_file_path, out_excel_file_type='xlsm'):
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wbxls = excel.Workbooks.Open(in_xls_file_path)
    in_xls_file_path = in_xls_file_path.replace('/', '\\')
    out_xlsx_or_xlsm_file_path = in_xls_file_path + out_excel_file_type[-1]
    # FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension, 52 for xlsm, no questions about containing VB script for xlsm
    if out_excel_file_type == 'xlsm':
        excel_file_format = 52
    elif out_excel_file_type == 'xlsx':
        excel_file_format = 51
    else:
        excel_file_format = 52  # or do some error corrections:
        # print('ERROR, wrong excel file type:', out_excel_file_type)
        # return None # sys.exit ('taihen taihen') # raise cthulhu
    wbxls.SaveAs(out_xlsx_or_xlsm_file_path, FileFormat=excel_file_format)
    wbxls.Close()
    excel.Application.Quit()
    return out_xlsx_or_xlsm_file_path
```

Also, sometime we have some sort of corrupted xlsx-file, and Excel start crying about it, and script stops, to autorecover it you can use this code, pay attention to xlsx files path, for example, this path won't work in this case:

resaved_xlsx_on_disk = 'c:/this_wont_work/2.xlsx' # usually works, but not with win32.client

```
corrupted_xlsx_on_disk = 'c:\\fyi_if_you_dont_use_two_backslashes_and_use_slashes_in_path_it_will_not_open\\1.xlsx'
resaved_xlsx_on_disk = r'c:\you_can_also_use_this\2.xlsx'
xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
# xl.Visible = True # otherwise excel is hidden (btw if corrupted it anyway show some message, but autoclose it)
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(corrupted_xlsx_on_disk, CorruptLoad=1)
xl.SendKeys("{Enter}", Wait=1)
xl.DisplayAlerts = 0
wb.SaveAs(resaved_xlsx_on_disk)  # You can try wb.Save(), but I can't get it to work :-(
wb.Close()
xl.Application.Quit()
```

===
upd. on 9 aug 2021:
Considering the code above, when using opposite operation - resaving xlsx to xls, often windows about Compatibility Check occures (also, if Excel just looks like hang up - that maybe because this window did not get focus and stays hidden between other windows), tl;dr, `excel.DisplayAlerts = False` do the job, code example (I will also check, maybe it applicable for xls->xlsx transformation without using this xlsm extension, if xls contains macroses):

```
import os
import win32com.client
import win32com

# if strange errors on start occures, delete everything from this path
# (maybe dynamic loading from now do this action unnecessary):
print(win32com.__gen_path__)


def resave_xlsx_files_as_xls(files_parent_dir):
    input_files = os.listdir(files_parent_dir)  # todo: use the glob, Luke!
    input_files = [files_parent_dir + i for i in input_files if i.endswith('.xlsx')]
    for input_file in input_files:
        print(input_file)
        if not os.path.isfile(input_file.replace('.xlsx', '.xls')):
            excel = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
            wbxls = excel.Workbooks.Open(input_file)
            # wbxls.DoNotPromptForConvert = True # seems that this line has no effect if uncommented
            # wbxls.CheckCompatibility = False # seems that this line also has no effect if uncommented
            excel.DisplayAlerts = False  # this line do the main job - compatibility check window did not shows up!
            # AFAIK this library hardly understand normal os.path.join or os.path.sep
            input_file = input_file.replace('/', '\\')
            input_file = input_file.replace('.xlsx', '.xls')
            # FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension, 52 for xlsm
            excel_file_format = 56
            # Compatibility check window will show up here on SaveAs line, you may did not locate it at first, cause it
            # usually don't get focus, so it may be hidden somewhere under couple of windows, best
            # way to find it - click "-" button on every window until wallpaper shows up, pressing
            # hotkeys like Win-D will not help - this command will hide this compatibility check
            # window also
            wbxls.SaveAs(input_file, FileFormat=excel_file_format)
            wbxls.Close()  # FileFormat = 56 is for .xls extension
            excel.Application.Quit()
        else:
            print('There is already converted file in folder!')

    output_files = os.listdir(files_parent_dir)
    output_files = [files_parent_dir + i for i in output_files if i.endswith('.xls')]
    return output_files


resave_xlsx_files_as_xls('c:/test/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
wb.Close(True) #if you need to save .xls file also
```

or using

```
wb.Close(False) # if you not decide to save .xls file
```

On the other hand, it may have other file opened, so when you use `excel.Application.Quit()` and those file does not save, excel will show confirmation dialog before closing.